# Custom CSS does not apply

Tags: theme, css

I'm using a Magento based On-line store and it seems many of the CSS changes I make on our test server work correctly however there seem to be many CSS changes I make that don't Work if they are related to the CSS you can modify using the Magento dashboard tools.

For an example, changing the colour of the price displayed on the Website will not work as it seems that in the Magento Backed a colour has been specified for " Link Color " that seems to override the colors I try to change any buttons, price etc too.

Is there a way of getting around this?

Cheers in advance

Here is a screenshot that shows that the line of CSS I modified[image: a screenshot showing my CSS modification is being overwritten by I can't find the code that's doing it.]

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after the changes?

Comment: Yes i have flushed both magento and browser cache

Comment: color: #FFC374 !important;

Comment: if you are using css merge functionality. just try to rebuild css after modify your custom one.

Comment: Can you tell in the backend where these CSS values are being specified?

Answer (score 0):

To remind, the CSS cache is refreshed by 
the most LEFT-BOTTOM button **Flush JavaScipt/CSS cache** ~ then it should work.

[image: Flash CSS cache]

Answer (score 0):

The clean way would look like this:
Find the right rule from the CSS in your screenshot on the top, exclude this part for example:

```
c,
b,
a {
color:red;
}
```

**a** has the wrong color so give **a** an own css:

```
c,
b {
color:red;
}

a {
color:green;
}
```

Search the source code to find the preformated css. Maybe its generated in a PHTMl. (head.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

If you want override inline style, you could use `!important` declaration:

```
.regular-price .price {
    color: e72526 !important;
}
```